# Audio Souce is not playing on exact time(delaying) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xPos;
    public float zPos;
    public GameObject theDest;
    public GameObject thePlayer;
    public int posNum = 1;
    public float moveSpeed = 0.02f;
    private bool isWait = false;

    public bool allowWalk;
    public bool hasSpotted;
    public bool readyToAttack;
    public bool hasReachedPlayer;
    public bool canRun;
    public bool canAttack;

    // Player hurt
    public int hurtType;
    public AudioSource[] Hurt;
    public GameObject hurtScreen;

    // Zombie Sounds
    public int growlType;
    public AudioSource[] Growl;
    public bool isGrowling;
    public bool canScream;
    void Start()
    {
        canScream = false;
        isGrowling = false;
        canAttack = false;
        canRun = true;
        hasReachedPlayer = false;
        hasSpotted = false;
        allowWalk = true;
        readyToAttack = false;
        xPos = theDest.transform.position.x;
        zPos = theDest.transform.position.z;
        theDest.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, theDest.transform.position.y, zPos);
        posNum += 1;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(hasSpotted){
            moveSpeed = 0.09f;
            if(readyToAttack){
                if(hasReachedPlayer){
                    canRun = false;
                    this.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("attack"); 
                        if(!canAttack){
                            StartCoroutine(AttackAnimFinished());
                        }   
                }else{
                    if(!canRun){
                        StartCoroutine(AllowRunning());
                    }
                    if(canRun){
                        this.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("run");
                        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, thePlayer.transform.position, moveSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                this.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("scream");
                StartCoroutine(ReadyForAttack());
            }
            if(!(thePlayer.transform.position.y > 1.5)){
                transform.LookAt(thePlayer.transform);
            }
        }else{
             // HERE ZOMBIE WILL GROWL WHEN WANDERING
             if(!isGrowling){
                 StartCoroutine(ZombieGrowlManager());
             }

            if(allowWalk){
                this.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("walk");
                transform.LookAt(theDest.transform);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, theDest.transform.position, moveSpeed);
                if(isWait){
                    StartCoroutine(Wait());
                }else{
                    StartCoroutine(Move());
                }
            }else{
                this.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle");
                StartCoroutine(allowWalking());
            }
        }
        // CALLING ZOMBIEGROWLMANAGER IS CALLED FOR SCREAM
        if(canScream){
            StartCoroutine(ZombieGrowlManager());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move(){
        moveSpeed = 0.01f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        isWait = true;
    }
    IEnumerator Wait(){
        moveSpeed = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        isWait = false;
    }

    IEnumerator allowWalking(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        allowWalk = true;
    }

    IEnumerator ReadyForAttack(){
        // CANSCREAM IS SET TRUE
        canScream = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        canScream = false;
        readyToAttack = true;
    }

    IEnumerator AllowRunning(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        canRun = true;
    }

    IEnumerator AttackAnimFinished(){
        canAttack = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8833f);
        if(gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<EnemyCasting>().closeToPlayer){  
            GlobalPlayerHealth.playerHealth -= 5;  
            hurtType = Random.Range(0,4);
            Hurt[hurtType].Play();
            hurtScreen.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("hurtScreenAnim");
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);
        canAttack = false;
    }

    // ZOMBIE GROWL AND SCREAM IS MANAGED    
    IEnumerator ZombieGrowlManager(){
        if(canScream){
            Growl[4].Play();
        }
        else{
            isGrowling = true;
            growlType = Random.Range(0,4);
            Growl[growlType].Play();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
            isGrowling = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have attach a zombie scream audio in 4th index of `Growl` array. I have coded it such that if `canScream` is true it will call `ZombieGrowlManager()`. In that it should play because of line `Growl[4].Play()`. I have enabled the `canScream` inside `ReadyForAttack()`. In my opinion after 3 secs the `canScream` should be disabled or in the time span of 3 secs `Growl[4]` should play.

But when i play the game and see in inspector, it only works after `canScream` is false. Therefore delaying on playing.

**See comments in CAPITAL to avoid reading/finding the code lines**

Comment: To me it looks like `canScream` stays true for multiple frames during 3 seconds so you would have concurrent Coroutines and restart the audio again and again so you will never hear it until the flag is finally set to false so the sound can finally continue to play to end. Every call to `Play` will restart the clip!

Comment: Actually you should rather use one single AudioSource and `PlayOneShot` which playes all sounds to end and even allows multiple parallel sounds

Answer (score 0):

Well i resolved to issue by adding and updating the following

```
public bool canScream2;
public AudioSource Scream;

if(canScream && !canScream2){
                StartCoroutine(ZombieGrowlManager());
             }

IEnumerator ZombieGrowlManager(){
        if(canScream){
            canScream2 = true;
            Scream.Play();
        }
        else{
            isGrowling = true;
            growlType = Random.Range(0,4);
            Growl[growlType].Play();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
            isGrowling = false;
        }
    }


IEnumerator ReadyForAttack(){
        canScream = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        canScream = false;
        canScream2 = false;
        readyToAttack = true;
    }
```

The issue was concurrent couroutines indeed.